# In which episode of Fairy Tail does the flashback where Erza joins Fairy Tail appear in?

Tags: fairy-tail

In what episode of Fairy Tail does a flashback occur in, showing how Erza joined Fairy Tail, and met Gray?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [episode 37](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_37) in the anime or [chapter 89](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_89) in the manga.

[image: Erza in color] [image: Erza]

Comment: Wow, the side-by-side really shows how much rougher of shape she was in according to the manga...